# Contradiction of computation of this:$\lim _{x\to 0^+} (\frac{({2}^{(e^{x^\frac32}+1)}-4)^2}{\sin^6{(\sqrt{x}})})$ with wolfram alpha?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, wolfram-alpha

I have claculated :$\lim _{x\to 0^+} (\frac{({2}^{(e^{x^\frac32}+1)}-4)^2}{\sin^6{(\sqrt{x}})})$  I have got $( 4\log 2))^2$ as shown below ,but [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(+2+%5E(+e%5E(x%5E(3%2F2)%2B1))-4+)%C2%B2%2Fsin%5E6(sqrt(x)),+x+to+0) assumed it equal  $\infty$  , then my question here where is the problem in my steps of evaluation ?

[image]

Comment: Here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(+2+%5E(+e%5E(x%5E(3%2F2))%2B1)-4+)%C2%B2%2Fsin%5E6(sqrt(x)),+x+to+0

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is a bracket misplaced in what you wrote in wolfram alpha

Comment: Specifically: the exponent on 2 is $e^{x^{3/2}}+1$ in the expression here, but $e^{x^{3/2}+1}$ in the linked code.